# JSPDF html2canvas - Image is showing at the bottom of the page and the multiple pages are not showing

Tags: javascript, jspdf

I have been trying to use the following code to display multiple pages.  The image is displaying at the bottom of the page.  How do I get the data to move up and also show the 3 different pages?

The below image shows the 3 pages (**data-customername**).

```
    html2canvas(document.querySelector("#formlayout")).then(canvas => {

        var imgData = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");

        var imgWidth = 210;
        var pageHeight = 295;
        var imgHeight = canvas.height * imgWidth / canvas.width;
        var heightLeft = imgHeight;
        var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'mm');
        var position = 0;

        doc.addImage(imgData, 'PNG', 0, position, imgWidth, imgHeight);
        heightLeft -= pageHeight;

        while (heightLeft >= 0) {
            position = heightLeft - imgHeight;
            doc.addPage();
            doc.addImage(imgData, 'PNG', 0, position, imgWidth, imgHeight);
            heightLeft -= pageHeight;

            doc.save('test.pdf');

        }
    });
```

**The PDF file looks like this.**

[image]

This is the id=**"#formLayout"** code

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Okay.  I seem have fixed the issue by moving my save pdf button to the top of the form and not at the bottom of the form.

When scrolling down and clicking the save pdf button cause the data to be moved off the form.

Comment: same issue for me and your answer works for me but that's not the solution there has to be a proper solution

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it works for me.

```
 var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg',1.0);
 var imgWidth = 210; 
 var pageHeight = 297;  
 var imgHeight = canvas.height * imgWidth / canvas.width;
 var heightLeft = imgHeight;
 var pdf = new jsPDF({orientation:'portrait', compress:true});
 var position = 5; // give some top padding to first page
            
 pdf.addImage(dataURL, 'JPEG', 5, position, imgWidth, imgHeight, undefined, 'FAST');
 heightLeft -= pageHeight;

 while (heightLeft >= 0) {
   position = position - 297; // limits each page with 297mm
   pdf.addPage();
   pdf.addImage(dataURL, 'JPEG', 5, position, imgWidth, imgHeight, undefined, 'FAST');
   heightLeft -= pageHeight;
 }

 pdf.save("Timesheet_Calculator");
```